# Is it possible to extract some data for users to amend and then use the amended data in the report?

Tags: ssrs

I am using SSRS 2008 r2.  I have a group of users that need to amend address details before they are printed from a report in CRM onto a pre-printed form. However we do not want to save these amendments into CRM. I have set them up a report that prints directly from the report screen onto a pre-printed form however they are not able to amend anything in the form in that format.

We have tried working with export to Word but the data moves around all the time and it is to be printed in specific spaces to appear on the pre-printed form in the correct place.

Is it possible to run the report and present the user with the address fields in a text box for them to amend, and then use the amended details in the text box as the address in the report?

Ideally we would want to be able to print directly from the screen after running the report.

I have tried many many searches and have not been able to find any problems similar to this.  I appreciate that this is not the normal way to use information in a CRM but this is data that needs to be changed for legal reasons on these specific forms.

Comment: Would it be possible using Parameters or Variables?  Would it work to pull the address fields as parameters in a text box, the user amends and then the new address text is passed as Parameter or variable to the report?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is interested I have worked out to do this in most instances:

- Create a parameter for address line 1 existing value in CRM and set default
  value to the field in CRM.
- Create a parameter to capture any address changes for address line 1.  Make sure that all are set to 'allow blank value"" ' and 'Visible'.
- Repeat the 2 steps above in order for each address line in CRM. [Example of Parameter Set Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0L64.jpg) 
  [Picture of Parameter set up when report is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhz1H.png)
- Add expression into report:

Example:

```
=iif(Parameters!AddressLine1Changes.Value<>""

, Parameters!AddressLine1Changes.Value

, Fields!address1_line1.Value)
```

As I said this works in most instances but at the moment it does not work where the CRM value is NULL and the user adds a value into the new parameter.  I have posted a new thread to get some help with that.
[Why is Text Parameter not accepting new value only when default value is blank or NULL?](https://superuser.com/questions/1438090/why-is-text-parameter-not-accepting-new-value-only-when-default-value-is-blank-o)