# Why is Text Parameter not accepting new value only when default value is blank or NULL?

Tags: parameters, ssrs

I have a group of users who need to amend address details pulled in a report before it is printed out.  We do not want these amendments to be saved or recorded on CRM.

I have worked out that using text parameters, to show the original values from CRM as the default value and a new text parameter to capture any changes(i.e. 2 parameters for each address line - 1 with default for reference and 1 for changes) works well for the following scenarios:

- if I want to remove an entry from one of the address fields thereby
  leaving it blank
- if I want to amend one of the address fields.
- if the original field is blank and I want it to stay that way

I am really struggling where the original field does not hold a value and therefore is blank or NULL.
The parameter is showing as a blank (which is correct) and I can type into the new parameter with the new value but when I run the report it is not displaying the new value.

I have tried a multitude of codes to try to get this sorted (some examples attached) but I am unable to get it to work.
[Single IIF code used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7fCn.jpg)
[IIF code with IsNothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USoS5.jpg)

Tried:

- checking for IsNothing on the original field data
- checking for IsNothing on the new parameter value
- Setting the parameter value to accept nulls
- changing the (IsNothing(AddressLine3)) to be (AddressLine3="")

Can anyone help with how to get the report to accept the new parameter value where there is no value in the original data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted this by adding

```
ISNULL(fieldname,'') as name
```

into all of the address lines.